# Replacing a substring consisting of a digit

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm a newbie programmer so sorry in advance if I'm asking a too-obvious question.

I program in c#(WPF).

I have a few strings that are built in this structure:

```
string str ="David went to Location 1 to have lunch";
string str2 ="Mike has to walk a mile facing north to reach Location 2";
```

how can I cut the "Location 1" out in the most elegant way to replace it with another string (that will probably hold the Restaurant's name, to continue this example)??

I thought of doing something like:

```
str.replace("Location 1", strRestaurantName);
```

but as it should be generic(to allow the replacement of all Location x), it should be something using `str.indexof`to get the digit's position(it can be a number between 1 and 20), only I can't get it to work...

Oh, and unfortunately my boss doesn't want me to use regular expressions, or I'd have it by now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can a string have more than one location?

Comment: "my boss doesn't want me to use regular expressions" - Your boss is a moron. Please let him know the professionals at StackOverflow insist upon this.

Comment: the substring(location X) can be once in the big string, but it can change places inside the sentence.

Comment: To prevent possible collisions, and to make the "template system" more obvious, I would recommend using something like "David went to TEMPLATE_LOCATION_1" or "David went to {Location 1}".

Answer (score 2):

You could also probably use Dictionary like:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> Restaurants = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Restaurants.Add("Location 1", "ABC Restaurant");
        Restaurants.Add("Location 2", "ABD Restaurant");
        Restaurants.Add("Location 3", "ABE Restaurant");
        Restaurants.Add("Location 4", "ABF Restaurant");
        Restaurants.Add("Location 5", "ABG Restaurant");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string str ="David went to Location 1 to have lunch";
      string str2 ="Mike has to walk a mile facing north to reach Location 2";

        MessageBox.Show( getRestaurant(str));
        // Result: David went to ABC Restaurant to have lunch

        MessageBox.Show( getRestaurant(str2));
        // Result: Mike has to walk a mile facing north to reach ABD Restaurant
    }

    private String getRestaurant(String msg)
    {
        String restaurantName = "";
        foreach (String loc in Restaurants.Keys)
        {
            if (msg.Contains(loc))
            {
                restaurantName = msg.Replace(loc, Restaurants[loc]);
                break;
            }
        }
        return  String.IsNullOrEmpty(restaurantName) ? msg : restaurantName;
    }
```

And you could also use **LINQ** to shorten the `getRestaurant` method like this:

```
    private String getRestaurant(String msg)
    {
        String restaurantName = Restaurants.Keys.FirstOrDefault<String>(v => msg.Contains(v));
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(restaurantName) ? msg : msg.Replace(restaurantName, Restaurants[restaurantName]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using formatting?
Something like this should do the trick:

```
string locationString = "some string";
string.Format("David went to {0} to have lunch", locationString);
```

This will result in the following sentence: `David went to some string to have lunch`

Of course, you can add as many strings as you want, and you can duplicate the same string by using the same variable number over and over (for example: `David went to {0} and {0} to have lunch` and this will expect only one `string` that will be inserted into the `{0}` locations.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I get the sentence as it is, I can't control the content, I have to replace the "Location X".

Comment: Then, indeed, your boss is an idiot :) Regex are exactly for these cases (for example, regex are used to verify the correctness of email addresses, otherwise almost impossible to verify)

Comment: @Jonathan Perry - I couldn't agree more :)

Comment: I guess without using regex, you should just build strings that contain the word `Location`, then space, and then a number, starting with the number 0. Loop through all of the strings you find and replace them with the correct strings. The stopping condition should be that you haven't found string "Location #" anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  I'm thinking:

1) You want to parameterize "Location 1=This restaurant", "Location 2=That place", etc in a list:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

2) Your code will cycle through each list item for each string.  Or perhaps cycle until it finds a match.

3) If possible, an event better approach might be to use C# placeholders instead of inventing your own "Location N" syntax, e.g. `str.Format("David went to {0} to have lunch", strRestaurantName);`, or `str.Format("David went to {0} to have lunch, then Mike has to walk a mile facing north to reach {1}", strRestaurantName, strHikingLocation);`

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said Regex really is the right solution here, but we can essentially do what the regex would be doing internally.

Note: I have not tested, or even compiled this code. This should match `Location (\d+)`.

```
string ReplaceLocation(string input, IList<string> replacements)
{
    string locString = "Location ";
    int matchDigitStart = 0;
    int matchDigitEnd = 0;
    int matchStart = 0;

    do{
        matchStart = input.IndexOf(locString, matchDigitStart);
        if(matchStart == -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Input string did not contain Location identifier", "input");
        }

        matchDigitStart = matchStart + locString.Length;
        matchDigitEnd = matchDigitStart;
        while(matchDigitEnd < input.Length && Char.IsDigit(input[matchDigitEnd]))
        {
            ++matchDigitEnd;
        }

    } while (matchDigitEnd == matchDigitStart);


    int locationId = int.Parse(input.Substring(matchDigitStart, matchDigitEnd - matchDigitStart));
    if(locationId > replacements.Count || locationId == 0 )
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Input string specified an out-of-range location identifier", "input");
    }

    return input.Substring(0, matchStart) + replacements[locationId - 1] + input.Substring(matchDigitEnd);
}
```